# boost intall on windows and typescript

Tags: windows, typescript, boost

I'd like to install boost on windows 10. I downloaded the package (1.64), launched boostrap, and got the fail log below. I indeed don't have typescript installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs . But I do have Visual Studio 2017 installed (working just fine).

Since I'm no specialist of windows, and doesn't want to try anything messy, I would appreciate any advice on this issue.

---

** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26430.12

** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

---

[ERROR:typescript.bat] TypeScript was not added to PATH since a valid installation was not found
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thanks to [Typescript Support for Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149606/typescript-support-for-visual-studio-2017)
Typescript was not installed by default with visual studio 2017. Running the installer as described in one of the answers in the linked question solved the problem.