# JavaScript .JS file is not included or nested under my Typescript .TS file in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I am running Visual Studio 2017, and I have a fine Typescript `.TS` file. I have made the following very advanced Typescript code:

```
var test = 'karl';
console.log(test);
```

I have made a `tsconfig.json` file, based on the default recommendation:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And now, when I save my Typescript file, it does generate a JS file.

However, two things surprise me: the JS file is not included in my VS solution, and the JS file is not nested under my Typescript file. The expected behaviour (also what I see here, [Typescript Support for Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149606/typescript-support-for-visual-studio-2017)), is that when it is saved, it will nest it under the Typescript file.

I also don't have a "nest" option after I included the JS file:

[image]

Comment: you might need to add `allowJs: true` to your `tsconfig`

Comment: @JasonSpradlin Didn't change anything unfortunately :-) Just tried